# A smoothly fading logo bug

Tags: javascript, jquery

So let's assume that i have a logo on top of a logo and one of them is hidden. Now if i move my mouse over the logo the logo would fade in smoothly and if the mouse leaves then the logo would fade out smoothly. I've got everything working all fine and dandy up to this point. What really annoys me however, is the fact that if i move my mouse over the logo rapidly then it flickers. I want it to be smooth at all times. Since i'm pretty new to javascript and jQuery then maybe someone here would know how to fix this bug. Hopefully not by rewriting the whole code, not that there's alot... Anyway here's the code:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).ready( function () {
          $('#img2').hide();
    });
    $('#logo').hover(       
        function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            $('#img2',$this).stop(true,true).fadeIn();
        },
        function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            $('#img2',$this).stop(true,true).fadeOut();
        }
    );
});
```

And [here's](http://jsfiddle.net/birdhouse/2hnvn/10/) the fiddle with the logo and all...

So i hope y'all understand what the problem is and what i'm trying to achieve here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to avoid unnecessary JavaScript animations, use CSS transitions instead.

**CSS:**

```
#img2 {
    transition: 1s;
    opacity: 0;
}
#img2:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Some more info from [CSS tricks](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/).
**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jonathan_Ironman/2hnvn/12/)**

Comment: That will do, but two ids in a selector are redundant.

Comment: Thanks mate! That's exactly what i was trying to create. :)

Comment: No problem, you should check **[here](http://caniuse.com/css-transitions)** which browsers you want to support though.